# Galaxy Nexus not connecting to router with WEP encryption

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, connection-issues, wep

My Samsung Galaxy Nexus (I9250) running Jelly bean 4.1.1 has problems connecting to a Wifi router with WEP encryption. I cannot change the WiFi encryption type.

Other devices are connecting to the network and working fine. The Nexus is connecting to other wifi networks properly. I have tried [WiFi Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kman.WifiManager) and other apps to connect.

Anyone facing a similar issue? Any solution to fix this issue?